# Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of mappings $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ for which $f(m) \le f(n)$ for $m \le n$. Show that $\mathcal F$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Does my attempt contain gap? Any suggestion is appreciated! Thank you so much!

---

> Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of mappings $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ for which $f(m) \le f(n)$ for $m \le n$. Show that $\mathcal F$ is uncountable.

---

**My attempt:**

Let $\mathcal F^\star$ be the set of strictly increasing mappings from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$. It's clear that $\mathcal F^\star \subseteq \mathcal F$ and thus $|\mathcal F^\star| \le |\mathcal F|$.

If $f\in \mathcal F^\star$, then $\operatorname{ran}f$ contains at least $2$ elements. Thus $|\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)| \le |\mathcal F^\star|$.

Hence $|\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)| \le |\mathcal F^\star| \le |\mathcal F|$. We know that $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable. It follows that $\mathcal F$ is uncountable.

---

**Update:** From users' comment and answer, I fixed my proof here.

We know that the set of bounded subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable and $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable. Thus the set of unbounded subsets of $\Bbb N$ is uncountable.

Furthermore, each unbounded subset of $\Bbb N$ corresponds to a unique mapping $f\in \mathcal F^\star$. Thus $\mathcal F^\star$ is uncountable. Since $|\mathcal F^\star| \le |\mathcal F|$, $\mathcal F$ is uncountable.

Comment: You are not getting arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Which kinds of subsets are you getting instead? You don't get an inclusion of all $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$ but only a subset. Is that still big enough? If not try another proof.

Comment: @AHusain I have fixed my proof and posted it as an update. Could you please check it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you conclude that $|\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|\le |\mathcal F^\star|$.

Let $g:\mathbb N \to \{ 0,1\}$ be an element of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$. Consider $f_g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ defined by
$$ f_g(n) = \sum_{k=0}^ng(k)$$
Note that $f_g\in\mathcal F$ for every $g\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$, and $$f_g=f_{g'}\iff g=g',$$ thus $g\mapsto f_g$ is an injection $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to\mathcal F$.

Comment: I have fixed my proof and posted it as an update. Could you please check it? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Akira what is your correspondence? There is one (there are many) but you don't say what it is

Comment: Actually, there is a unique correspondence for each unbounded subset of $\Bbb N$. I implicitly appealed to this theorem *Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb N$ without a greatest element. Then there exists a unique, strictly increasing, and surjective mapping $f:\Bbb N \to A$*. I will edit to add this point in my proof.

Comment: @Akira To $A$ yes. But the question is is about the larger class of maps to $\mathbb N$ and there are many of these, yours being one of them.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you meant by *the larger class of maps to $\mathbb N$*. Is *class* equivalent to $set$ in your comment? Please elaborate!

Comment: @Akira Yes, set. Simplest example, let $A\mapsto f_A$ be your unique map  and consider $A\mapsto f_A + 1$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_A + 1$?

Comment: @Akira the addition of functions, where 1 is the function taking only the value 1

Comment: Honestly, I have never seen that notation :) My fix is fine?

Comment: @Akira 1 is abused all the time, you'll get used to it :) other examples $2f_A$, and so on. if you write everything out carefully it will be.

Comment: Now I seem to understand your notation, $(f_A + 1)(a)=f_A (a)+1$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: @Akira not quite, the domain is $\mathbb N$ (as enforced by the question)

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much! $A=\operatorname{ran}f_A$.

Answer (score 1):

For each not empty A in P(N) find an increasing
f$_A:$N -> N in F with range f$_A$ = A.

Thus there is a surjection h:F -> P(N) - {empty set}
and F is uncountable.

Comment: $A=\varnothing$. You can't do this for each $A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: It is not a bijection.  12222... and 11222... both map to {0,1}. @Brahadeesh

Comment: (To be formatted correctly, the dollar signs should enclose each whole mathematical statement, and \to makes an arrow when inside the dollar signs.)

Comment: @WilliamElliot Maybe I wrong. I think $12222\cdots$ and $11222\cdots$ both map to $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Sorry, can you ask a complete question please?